# Query string with spaces

Tags: mysql

Is is possible to query string with spaces, a sentence for example, I have following query:

```
select id_group from groups where title = 'some title with spaces'
```

And I don't get any results although I have exact title in my database. I also tried with `like` but it's the same

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Your problem is not with the spaces. Give us the specific title if you can so we can diagnose it.

Comment: I inputed example title in database like in my question 'some title with spaces'

Comment: Run this UPDATE table set column= TRIM(column);

Comment: give us results for this query `select concat('[', title, ']') from groups`

Comment: all lower case in both database and in query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to get all titles with a white space.

```
select id_group from groups where title like '% %';
```

But you may find performance issues if there are many number of records and if the column is not indexed.

Comment: This query worked, it seems I misspelled my query, I'll mark this as solution

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible, maybe  try with double quotes? y just tried in my database

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Faq` 
WHERE faq_pregunta =  "chao que te vaya bien"
```

and it works

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your query. The only explanation is that *there just isn't any row that satisfies the condition*.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. if you are using phpmyadmin you can press on "sql" and then try your code directly in the database. The problem i think is that you may use lack of ' or " or some other type of symbol. The problem can also be that you havent typed the exact same line. It is important to use capital on the same places and so on.